# How to display two decimal values in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple program below. The output is 64.5 it only shows one decimal value but I wanted it to display the last two decimal values.

Ex. Your change is 64.50 USD

How can I achieve this in dart/flutter?

```
void main() {

  double money = 80.00;
  double price = 15.50;

  double change = money - price;

  print('Your change is $change USD');
}
```

Comment: BTW, I would highly recommend that you do not store currency as `double`.  You'd be much better off storing the number of cents (or whatever the smallest indivisible unit of currency is) as `int` and then printing it in a friendlier format at the end.  If you use `double`, you'll find that $0.10 + $0.10 + $0.10 is not $0.30 due to [floating point error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This:

```
void main() {

  double money = 80.00;
  double price = 15.50;

  double change = money - price;

  print('Your change is ${change.toStringAsFixed(2)} USD');
}
```

[check here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [intl package from google](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
var formatter = new NumberFormat.currency(locale: "en_US", symbol: "$");
print('Your change is {formatter.format(change)} USD');
```